# iPhone SDK Point to a specific location

Tags: iphone, sdk, mapkit, compass-geolocation, cllocation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone Compass GPS Direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130821/iphone-compass-gps-direction)

Hi, I'm trying to develop an application that use the GPS and Compass of the iPhone in order to point some sort of pointer to a specific location (like the compass always point to the North).
The location is fixed and I always need the pointer to point to that specific location no matter where the user is located.
I have the Lat/Long coordinates of this location but not sure how can I point to that location using the Compass and the GPS... any help will be appreciated.