# How do I point compass at my destination?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, gps, cllocation

I am creating an app that will point a simple arrow in the direction of a GPS coordinate I have plotted out. So I am talking my current location lat and long, so lat1, lon1 is the current location... then comparing them against a static coordinate of lat  and long called lat2, lon2.

I have spent HOURS researching and testing, but I keep on getting the same problem. It's very aggravating. As soon as I start to drive towards my destination the arrow is all out of whacked when using the iPhone's built in GPS/compass. It will sometimes show the arrow the complete opposite side of where it needs to be, hanging to the right... pretty much nothing that is solid.

Here is the current code I am running

cpLocLat = 43.026629;

cpLocLon = -78.867188;

Those are float values and the coordinates of where I want to drive to.

```
float lat1 = self.locManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
float lat2 = cpLocLat;
float lon1 = self.locManager.location.coordinate.longitude;
float lon2 = cpLocLon;

float heading = atan2(sin(lon2 - lon1) * cos(lat2), cos(lat1) * sin(lat2) - sin(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(lon2 - lon1));

heading = RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(heading);

if (heading < 0) {
    heading = heading + 360;
}
```

I use this function every time the locationManager didUpdateToLocation delagate is called. Once I have that information, it is used in the locationManager didUpdateHeading delagte with the following:

```
CGAffineTransform where  = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians((degrees - newHeading.magneticHeading)));

[self.compassContainer2 setTransform:where];
```

and here is the degressToRadians macro

```
#define degreesToRadians(x) (M_PI * x / 180.0)
```

So whenever I run this code it is failing epically and is making me go nuts!

BTW - I have used the following URLs for reference

http://www.shawngrimes.me/2011/07/calculating-heading-with-corelocation/

[Using Compass to point to actual coordinate location instead of just North](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145465/using-compass-to-point-to-actual-coordinate-location-instead-of-just-north)

[Point to location using compass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092845/point-to-location-using-compass)

Comment: Are you sure the heading calculation trigonometrical formula is correct?

Comment: I have tried several other formulas including the links I have posted.. all resulting to similar effects.

Comment: Make sure you're not calling it for invalid locations (accuracy is negative)

Comment: Yes I am calling from valid locations.. logging it all. still no dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, the formula for the initial bearing according to the Haversine formula is:

> θ =   atan2(  sin(Δlong).cos(lat2),
>   cos(lat1).sin(lat2) − sin(lat1).cos(lat2).cos(Δlong) )

which seems to be exactly what you used. According to the `man` entry, you might have to use the reverse order of the two arguments to `atan2`:

```
ATAN2(3)                 BSD Library Functions Manual                 ATAN2(3)

NAME
     atan2 -- arc tangent function of two variables

SYNOPSIS
     ....
     float
     atan2f(float y, float x);
```

So `y` comes before `x`. Maybe that is the error.
Also, make sure that the coordinate deltas (lat2-lat1 etc.) are in *radians*.

Comment: Yes this seemed to get the job done!, Just need to do some calibration to tweek it out. thank you.

Comment: Send me your paypal and ill buy you a coffee :)

Comment: can u share the exact code or how to show the direction to destination location please, i too facing same problem