# Point to direction of a GPS position

Tags: javascript, gps, compass-geolocation, direction, azimuth

I got the azimuth of a point, the compass heading and an api which can set an arrow to a certain direction (0 is top, 90 is right, 180 is bottom, 360 is top)

how i calculate the correct value for the arrow if i want it to point to the point which i took the azimuth form?

thank you

Comment: I don't understand your question :(

Comment: A point doesn't have an azimuth, the vector between two points does. A compass heading is effectively an azimuth. The directions in the OP are those used for navigation (e.g. by surveyors and cartographers), they have a different zero and direction of rotation to mathematic angles. When you formulate a real question, you can be helped with that.

Comment: sorry, let me try again: i got the latitude and longitude of two points, my current location and a target location. what i also got is the compass heading. so how do i calculate in which direction the target location is?

Answer (score 4):

The formula for heading between two lat/long coords is:

=atan2(cos(lat1)*sin(lat2)-sin(lat1)*cos(lat2)*cos(lon2-lon1), 
       sin(lon2-lon1)*cos(lat2))

where lat2/lon2 is your end point, lat1/lon1 is your start point.

Your answer will be between -pi and pi radians.

To get the heading in degrees, convert your radians to degrees then do: (degrees+360)%360 = heading. The heading will then be 0 for north, 90 for east etc.

The compass heading means nothing, unless you need to adjust your heading from true north to magnetic north.

Answer (score 0):

[iPhone Compass GPS Direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130821/iphone-compass-gps-direction/4076257#4076257)